# For Sending Html Template in mail, iterate Only Second table in html

Tags: c#, .net

I have used Html Template to send mail in this HTML Template i have used a table within a table to send mail Everything works Fine but i am getting html in this Format [image]

and how i Want is Like This
[image]

My C# Code For Generating Html Mail is

```
var TemplatePath = userDetail.UserTypeTemplate.EmailTemplatePath;
                toEmail = userDetail.Email; 
                fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminMail"];
                var sbMail = new StringBuilder();
                sbMail.Replace("{Name}", userDetail.Name);
                sbMail.Replace("{CurrentDate}", currentDateTime.ToString("d"));
                foreach (var tender in userTenders)
                {
                    using (var sReader = new StreamReader(TemplatePath))
                    {
                        sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderTitle}", tender.TenderTitle);
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderID}", tender.TenderID.ToString());
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderType}", tender.TenderTypeName);
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderValue}", tender.TenderValue.ToString("₹ 0,0", InCulture));
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderEMD}", tender.TenderEMD);
                        sbMail.Replace("{Location}", tender.Location);
                        sbMail.Replace("{OrgName}", tender.OrgName);
                        sbMail.Replace("{LastDateForSubmission}", tender.LastDateForSubmission.ToString("d"));
                        sbMail.Replace("{SubProductCatName}", tender.SubProductCatName);
                        sbMail.Append("<br />");
                    }
                }
```

the main Problem is when i am using .Replace with Name it's Starts Repeating Whole Table and When i am Using this .Replace method outside Foreach loop it's not reading the Name
Can Someone Help Plz....
Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your template is not suited for what you try to achieve. I assume that your template containse the header info (Name and Date) and one entry for a tender. When you read the whole template each time you repeat the name and date as well as the tender entries.

What you need to do is to have one template for header info (Name and Date) and one template for the tender records. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
var TemplatePath = userDetail.UserTypeTemplate.EmailTemplatePath;
var headerTemplate = userDetail.UserTypeTemplate.EmailHeaderTemplatePath;
                toEmail = userDetail.Email; 
                fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminMail"];
                var sbMail = new StringBuilder();
                using (var sReader = new StreamReader(headerTemplate))
                {
                    sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                    sbMail.Replace("{Name}", userDetail.Name);
                    sbMail.Replace("{CurrentDate}", currentDateTime.ToString("d"));
                }

                foreach (var tender in userTenders)
                {
                    using (var sReader = new StreamReader(TemplatePath))
                    {
                        sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderTitle}", tender.TenderTitle);
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderID}", tender.TenderID.ToString());
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderType}", tender.TenderTypeName);
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderValue}", tender.TenderValue.ToString("₹ 0,0", InCulture));
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderEMD}", tender.TenderEMD);
                        sbMail.Replace("{Location}", tender.Location);
                        sbMail.Replace("{OrgName}", tender.OrgName);
                        sbMail.Replace("{LastDateForSubmission}", tender.LastDateForSubmission.ToString("d"));
                        sbMail.Replace("{SubProductCatName}", tender.SubProductCatName);
                        sbMail.Append("<br />");
                    }
                }
```

This should allow you to make one header record and as many tender records as you need..

Comment: thnx @Zaphod  you save my life

Comment: Great I can help. Please mark question as answered if this solved it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it by adding 3 html template
read header and footer only once and iterate central Content
My Code is Like

```
                var TemplatePath = userDetail.UserTypeTemplate.EmailTemplatePath;
                var HeaderTemplateForPaidUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HeaderTemplateForPaidUser"];
                var FooterTemplateForPaidUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FooterTemplateForPaidUser"];
                toEmail = userDetail.Email;
                fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminMail"];
                var sbMail = new StringBuilder();
                using (var sReader = new StreamReader(HeaderTemplateForPaidUser))
                {
                    sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                    sbMail.Replace("{Name}", userDetail.Name);
                    sbMail.Replace("{CurrentDate}", currentDate.ToString("D"));
                }

                foreach (var tender in userTenders)
                {
                    using (var sReader = new StreamReader(TemplatePath))
                    {
                        sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderTitle}", tender.TenderTitle);
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderID}", tender.TenderID.ToString("####"));
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderType}", tender.TenderTypeName);
                        sbMail.Replace("{TenderValue}", tender.TenderValue.ToString("₹ 0,0", InCulture));

                        sbMail.Append("<br />");
                    }
                }

                using (var sReader = new StreamReader(FooterTemplateForPaidUser))
                {
                    sbMail.Append(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                }
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the footer in my first reply. Glad you figured that one out.